# Get the textbox to display values from Datetimepicker by using buttons to go forward or back through the dates

Tags: winforms

I want to be able to go through dates by clicking the <-button (displaying dates after todays date) and > - button (displaying dates that are in the future). However when I run the program I can only click one time and the change the date but I cant seem to do that several times.

Maybe a total beginner question but I have tried at this for several hours and cant figure it out.My questions is how do I handle the button-click event so that I can click several times and display dates in the textbox. I tried using if-statements and looping for some reason but other then that I'm stuck.

Oh and this is the code that I have written:

```
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        tbDatum.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();

    }

    private void buBak_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
        tbDatum.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();


    }

    private void buFram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
        tbDatum.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DateTime.Today will always return today's date. This is resolved by using the value in your tbDatum textbox.  In the code below, I am taking the value from the textbox and converting it to a [datetime object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx).  I then call the AddDays method with the specified number of days.

Updated button clicks:

```
    private void buBak_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(tbDatum.Text).AddDays(-1);
        tbDatum.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
    }

    private void buFram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(tbDatum.Text).AddDays(1);
        tbDatum.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @JAMLA if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.